# Running a Datasnap Client Application on a Mobile Device

Tags: delphi, deployment, sql-server-2012, datasnap

I have recently finished building a Multi-Tier database Application using the datasnap technology in Delphi. I have built the datasnap Client app in Delphi-Object Pascal, and linked it to a datasnap server app that communicates with SQL Server 2012. 
When I run my Client app on the Windows desktop(64bit), it works just fine; it connects to the datasnap server, and can reads and update the database. However, when i run it on an Android Device (Samsung galaxy 4.2.2),while the server is running, it deploys successfully and opens, but whenever i try to use any functions such as clicking a button, it freezes and then sends me the error:

> Socket Error #110 Connection timed out.

I have a checkbox function with a statement that opens the connection to the server once checked. When I attempt to check this box, it gives me the same error above.

How can i run the app on a mobile device, and have it communicate with the datasnap server successfully?

Comment: What Delphi version are you running? Have you checked to make sure that your app has the required uses permissions?

Comment: i am Using XE8. Yes, I have checked and verified the permissions in all uses clauses

Comment: This is an incredibly general question. It could be something about the wireless network that isn't working. Use process of elimination to determine the cause. Use the simplest app possible to eliminate other unlikely conclusions.